# jQuery ColorBox confirm override modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal, colorbox

How would I use [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) to create a 'confirm override' modal dialog that can interupt a form submission until 'yes' is clicked.

[Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal) has a [similar function](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/), but I much prefer colorbox's implementation and documentation, otherwise I'd use the latter.

Comment: Voted to close this question as no longer relevant, as Eric helped troubleshoot his implementation of the confirm override in Simple Modal.

Comment: Marked Eric's answer as solution instead of closing - Thanks for the help Eric.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't help you with ColorBox, but if you have a specific question or issue with SimpleModal, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Eric, I've asked a specific question for one of my problems here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869188/jquery-upgrade-breaks-simplemodal-confirm-implementation

Comment: Also, probably just me, but the jumpy animation between href anchors on your project page really gets on my nerves ;)

Comment: Ha-ha. Sorry, guess I can't please everyone ;) I'm already working on a new design for me site, so I'll keep that in mind...

Comment: Eric, it would be nice on a non-technical site, but on the 15th visit to troubleshoot a problem, it gets grating. But like you say, you can't and shouldn't please everyone ;)

Comment: ARE YOU SERIOUS??? What kind of answer is this and why is this even marked as an answer??

Comment: @Lol coder - while I completely agree with you (it should have been a comment, I was just figuring out SO at the time), why in the world are you worried about something from 16 months ago?

Answer (score 1):

You can use overlayClose property to false to make disable closing when you click outside the colorbox div and by setting closebutton property to false will hide close button . That is how you can make colorbox div as modal.

code : `$.colorbox({overlayClose:false,closebutton:false});`