# SimpleModal Confirm fails to submit form

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm trying to use jQuery [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) Confirm to show a Yes/No confirmation when a form is submitted.

I had modified the [demo here](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) (last in list), as follows, to catch and block the form submission.

However, this only seems to work with jQuery 1.2.6 a recent upgrade to 1.3.2 stops the form from being submitted if yes is clicked.

I can't however, work out what in my code is now wrong / incompatible. The demo (which is a simple window.href implementation works in both versions).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('input.delete').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(e.target);
        confirm("Really delete this event?", function () {
            target.click()
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: is the delete input a "submit" input type?

Comment: Funka - yes, it's the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with a combination of Funka and Eric's advice:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
$('.deleteconfirm').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         confirm("Really delete this event?", function () {
         $('form#deleteform').submit()
         });
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?  The idea is to catch (and fire!) on the submit event, not the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
        var f = this;
        confirm("Really delete this event?", function () {
            $(f).submit();
        });
        return false;  // cancel the initial submit event
    });
});
```

Hope this is of some help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Jon,

The demos are the site are using the latest jQuery, so I don't think it is an issue between the version and SimpleModal.

What about trying:

```
target.submit();
```

-Eric

Comment: Same result. Pop-up appears, 'Yes' action doesn't submit anything.